# UITableView click not calling didselectrowAtIndexpath (last cell not clickable in ipad)ios Xcode 6.2

Tags: ios, ipad, scrollview, tableview

In my project,i have a scrollView--> view--> and i have the following elements inside this view(i named it my mainView).
1.mpmovieplayer
2.view(with two labels)
2.UITableView

I went through many answers mentioned in stackoverflow but they are not working for me.Can someone help me fix this issue?
How to set the mainview height and the UIScrollView contentsize properly?The last two rows of the tableview are not clickable in iPad.It is working perfectly in iPhone.

Is this an autolayout issue?Thanks in advance.

this is my code in viewDidAppear:

```
float sizeOfContent = 0;
int i;
for (i = 0; i < [_scrollView.subviews count]; i++) {
    UIView *view =[_scrollView.subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    sizeOfContent += view.frame.size.height;
}

// Set content size for scroll view

_scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(_scrollView.frame.size.width, sizeOfContent);
```

what should be my mainview frame?The last three cells are not clickable.Anybody face any similar issue?

Any suggestions are appreciated....

Comment: anyone???any suggestions?

Comment: Hopefully, your mainview frame matches the bounds of scrollview. You can NSLog it. To visually see frames for your views, use borderColor.

Comment: What should be the frame height for mainview and the scrollview?like mainview height>scrollview height?

Comment: As far as views are inside scrollview, they can have any height. You just take care that scrollview's contentsize should be able to adjust your view's height. Just for debug, give your mainview height and scrollview content height a large hard coded value. See if it works.

Comment: Its not working @iAnum..now the scrollview will scroll all the way down.All the cells are displaying.But not all are clickable.

Answer (score 0):

First I would check whether there is a view on top of this two cells or not.

- use Xcdoe -> Debug -> View Debugging -> Capture View Hierarchy/ Show Frames. It 
  sounds like a misslayouted view which catches the touch event but I could be wrong.

Are there any broken constraints in your xcode debug console?

Comment: this table when scroll to top also works the same..the cells at the bottom will not work

Comment: How about other UITableViewDelegate calls like _willSelectRowAtIndexPath:_? Do they work?

Comment: willSelectRowAt IndexPath also get called for a specific area of the the second last cell.it  is not getting called for the last cell.the issue is with the size i guess.But i dont know where to correct.